# "I will live in Glasgow for one to two years"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-structure

I know usually "to" is used with "from" as in “From Monday to Wednesday I was in.”

But could you please tell me if I could  use "to" with "for" as in

> "I will live in Glasgow for two to three years"

Comment: Are you suggesting that "or" is used with "for" more than with other prepositions? If so, why do you say that? Did you read it somewhere? Is it your own conclusion? Please explain.

Comment: @MarclnManhatten.No that is not what I am suggesting.Actually  I want to know If I could use "to" with "for" as in "I will live in "Glasgow" for two to three years".These are my own conclusion

Comment: In that case, I recommend deleting the second sentence, because I think that it distracts from your question.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan as you said i deleted that second sentence.Could you pls enlighten me on my intended question?

Comment: Yes, _two to three years_ is fine if you expect the stay to last between two and three years.

Comment: The 1st sentence needs an object such as a noun phrase, e.g.  *in my friend's home*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use to with for in this sentence.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].

Comment: I will make sure to attach references with my answers @Glorfindel.